# Jquery dialog submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dialog

yesterday I started working on a Jquery Dialog box to replace the default confirm box that jquery has... I came across an issue and all the tutorials I see tell me to use .submit() on my form but that does not seem to want to play nicely (or play at all for that matter)

This is the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CKnfJ/4/)

And now this is my javascript that is not working for me :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            var currentForm;
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: false,
                height: 310,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    'Enter Queue': function() {
                        currentForm.submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    $("#signinform").submit(function() {
        currentForm = this;
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

The problem is happening at the "Enter Queue" button. Pretty much the scenario (as it is shown on the jsfiddle) is I need users to acknowledge the rules of the office, and if they do so they click on a check-box, once they do so then they click Submit, which then sends a dialog explaining to the user what they are getting into. However for some reason the "Enter Queue" button does nothing. I am quite confused. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out last night with the help of jquery website and a lot of google-ing. Thanks to the both of you for your help and time it took for the answers. + 1

This is my solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var Form = $("#signinform");
        $(function() 
        {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog(
            {
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                draggable: false,
                height: 320,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: 
                {
                    'Cancel': function() 
                    {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        Form.data("confirmProgress", false);
                    },
                    'Submit Information': function() 
                    {
                        Form.submit();
                        Form.data("confirmProgress", false);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        Form.submit(function() 
        {
            if (!$(this).data("confirmProgress")) 
            {
                $(this).data("confirmProgress", true);
                $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        });
    });
    // Everything under this is the Jquery for my second Dialog that has always been working, the issue was the above dialog which is now fixed.
 $(document).on('click', "#Cancel", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>studentlogin_controller/studentlogin';
        $("#dialog-noconfirm").dialog(
        {
            resizable: false,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            draggable: false,
            height: 320,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: 
            {
                "Cancel": function() 
                {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Go Back": function() 
                {
                    window.location.href = href;
                },
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why not select an existing answer? you did not even explain how you solved it. Clearly they were what fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

It's because your re-using the `$(document).on('submit', "#signinform", function(e)` method
which got `e.preventDefault();` for first instruction when you call `$('#signinform').submit();`.

You need to set a temporary variable to see wether you come from your code or the submit button.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mYte8/) with a working test, but you should do something nicer =)

EDIT : Javascript is an asynchronous langage, it means that your `$('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');` doesn't block and just modify the html, so the submit event always will return false -> it will never be sent.

So I get that [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKnfJ/5/) which not really works like you want but if you trigger the submit button a second time after clicked the Enter Queue button it will work, so i'm wondering why the submit() method don't work when called from here.

A method you could use is to send the form with ajax (look at [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in jquery) and then redirect your user with something like window.location = "yourpage".

Comment: Does not work I'm afraid. I updated my JSfiddle with your instructions. Whats happening is now the form just submits without the dialog being needed to get clicked on.

Comment: Well the reason why this is buggy is right, your e.preventDefault() mess it up, i'm trying to make a better jsfiddle

Comment: Updated my last code. I added separation between the Opening of that specific dialog and the submission of the form. The "Enter Queue" button still does not perform an action.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tzJV/1/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.enterQueue=false;
    $("#signinform input:submit").on('click',function() {
        return getDialog(window.enterQueue);            
    });

    function getDialog(enterQueue){
        if(!enterQueue){
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: true,
                draggable: false,
                height: 310,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    'Enter Queue': function() {
                        window.enterQueue=true;
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $("#signinform input:submit").trigger('click');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else 
            return true;
    }
```

});

Comment: Thanks for you time! I posted my answer which I came up with last night. +1 for your answer though.